# Testing Aspect with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to test a class where a private method is annotated with custom annotation implementation. Is there a way to test this with Mockito? How should i inject the aspect implementation using Mockito annotations?

```
public class XYZ {
  @retryOnException(exception=Exception.class)
  private void doSomething()
  {
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Test what exactly?  What behaviour of the class are you trying to verify with your test?

Comment: I wanted to check if I throw the exception (using mockito) from within doSomething() does it retry the method as promised by the Aspect @retryOnException.

Comment: So you're actually testing that the annotation works, not that the method works?  In that case, can you make a dummy class for that purpose, within the test class for the annotation itself?

Comment: What do you use to wire up the AOP?

Comment: Why would you even want to test a private method? You should test behaviour not implementation. What is more I think what you want to achieve is to create some integration test that would boot the whole context together with aspects - I don't understand why you would like to check it at the point of a unit test. You can write a separate unit test for the aspect itself.

Comment: this question miss a lot of informations....